# Adding feature to an Apache v2 package

Tags: license-compatibility, mit, apache-2.0

I'm working on one npm package based on another one but with another approach, this package is licenced under Apache v2 and I want to use MIT. After some use of my package I've noticed I need to use the feature that the licenced code provides, but this package is not mantained since midyear of 2014 and a PR to this package is not an option.

Can I modify and include this package logic into my own package and publish it without any issue? Should I add some reference to the other package? If I should refer the other project what things should I do/include on my own package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should comply with the terms of the Apache License. If you copy AL-licensed source code verbatim, you should keep that license on that source code. if you make a derived work, you can change the license, but you have to comply with the terms of the license. All that you need to know can be found [here](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html); I quote:

> I'VE MADE IMPROVEMENTS TO THE APACHE CODE; MAY I DISTRIBUTE THE
> MODIFIED RESULT?
>
> Absolutely -- subject to the terms of the Apache
> license, of course. You can give your modified code away for free, or
> sell it, or keep it to yourself, or whatever you like. Just remember
> that the original code is still covered by the Apache license and you
> must comply with its terms. Even if you change every single line of
> the Apache code you're using, the result is still based on the
> Foundation's licensed code. You may distribute the result under a
> different license, but you need to acknowledge the use of the
> Foundation's software. To do otherwise would be stealing.
>
> If you think your changes would be found useful by others, though, we
> do encourage you to submit them to the appropriate Apache project for
> possible inclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll add a NOTICE with the refence to the based package to comply with apache's requirements, then I'll publish it under MIT.