# How to mark a copied Apache v2 piece of code?

Tags: apache-2.0, code-snippets

As stated in the tile, I want to know how should one mark code(functions or pieces of code smaller than 50% of the source file) copied from non copyleft sources (e.g Apache) ?

Comment: This might be relevant http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/adding-feature-to-an-apache-v2-package but I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do it this way:

1. I add a proper Apache notice and copyright at the top of the file
2. I document in comments where I took the code from and what I took
3. I document in comments any changes I did
4. I add a copy of the Apache license to go with the code
5. if originally present, I copy and carry with the code any NOTICE-like file that was with the original code

Comment: That would be a good solution if you accept that the rest of the file be covered by the Apache license as well. What if you want to put your own changes under a copyleft license, or keep them proprietary?

Comment: @Zimmi48 If your choice of other licenses is compatible with the Apache license (say proprietary or MIT/BSD or L/GPLv3) then you can use the same approach for your code and these other licenses in the same file. 
e.g. just document each section with a proper notice and comments.Though it is usually saner to split things in different files IMHO.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne but then wouldn't it be easier to copy the whole source file containing the Apache license and from your proprietary code just to call the functions/methods you need (of course when no change is required)?

Comment: @florinx: in many cases it would be, but this is not what you asked as a question ;)

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne You are technically right, finally it's about good documentation :)